# Distorted Bitmap File

Tags: c++, c, binary

I am writing a program that copies a .bmp file and write it to another file to manipulate it( mirror and invert colors specifically). The .bmp that is written comes out distorted. Does anyone see any problems? I've been up for hours working on this and my brain is fried at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct BitmapFileHeader {

    uint16_t type;
    uint32_t size;
    uint16_t reserved_1;
    uint16_t reserved_2;
    uint32_t offset;

};
struct BitmapInfoHeader {

    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
    uint16_t planes;
    uint16_t bitcount;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t imagesize;
    uint32_t x_pixels_per_meter;
    uint32_t y_pixels_per_meter;
    uint32_t color_used;
    uint32_t color_important;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct Pixel {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage : %s input_file output_file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fin;
    FILE *fout;
    BitmapFileHeader bfh;
    BitmapInfoHeader bih;

    fin = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if (nullptr == fin) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    if (sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) != fread(&bfh, 1, sizeof(bfh), fin)) {
        printf("Unable to read bitmap file header. \n");
        return -2;
    }

    if (sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) != fread(&bih, 1, sizeof(bih), fin)) {
        printf("Unable to read bitmap info header. \n");
        return -3;
    }

    printf("Size of File Header = %lu\n", sizeof(BitmapFileHeader));

    int8_t first = (bfh.type >> 8) & 0xff;
    int8_t second = bfh.type & 0xff;

    if ( (first != 'M') && (second != 'B') ){
        printf("Input file is not a Bitmap file. \n");
        return -4;
    }

    printf("File type = %c%c\n", first, second);
    printf("File size = %u\n", bfh.size);
    printf("File offset = %u\n", bfh.offset);
    printf("File width = %u\n", bih.width);
    printf("Info size = %u\n", bih.size);

    uint32_t padding_bytes = 0;
    uint32_t row_bytes_final = bih.width * sizeof(Pixel);
    uint32_t row_bytes_initial = row_bytes_final;

    do{
        uint32_t rem = row_bytes_final % 4;

        if (rem != 0) {
            row_bytes_final += 1;
        }

        padding_bytes = row_bytes_final - row_bytes_initial;

    } while( (row_bytes_final % 4) != 0);


    fseek(fin, bfh.offset, SEEK_SET);

    Pixel *p = new Pixel[bih.height * bih.width];

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bih.height; i++) {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < bih.width; j++) {
            uint32_t index = i * bih.width + j;
            fread(&p[index], 1, sizeof(Pixel), fin);
        }

       if (padding_bytes > 0) {
            fseek(fin, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            fputc('\0', fin);

       }
      //  fseek(fin, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    fclose(fin);


    fout = fopen(argv[2], "wb");

    if(nullptr == fout) {
        perror(argv[2]);
        return -5;
    }

    if(sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) != fwrite(&bfh, 1, sizeof(bfh), fout)) {
        printf("Unable to write bitmap file header.\n");
        return -6;
    }

    if(sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) != fwrite(&bih, 1, sizeof(bih), fout)) {
        printf("Unable to write bitmap info header.\n");
        return -7;
    }

    fseek(fout, bfh.offset, SEEK_SET);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bih.height; i++) {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < bih.width; j++) {
            uint32_t index = i * bih.width + j;
            fwrite(&p[index], 1, sizeof(Pixel), fout);
        }

       if (padding_bytes > 0) {
            fseek(fout, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            fputc('\0', fout);
        }

      //  fseek(fout, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);
    }



    fclose(fout);
    delete[] p;


    return 0;


}
```

Comment: It seems you want to read pixel by pixel - you have two loops by rows and cols, so why in `fread(&p[index], sizeof(Pixel), bih.width, fin);` you are passing `bih.width` ? Rather should be `1` there. Also in writing you have the same issue.

Comment: @rafix07 I changed that per suggestion of someone else. Nonetheless, It doesn't change the outcome of the file. I've updated the code.

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to analyze the erroneous file, with some tool (I have no idea about existence of such) or by hand. I'd rather do the latter because it will take less time than to search a tool. Then, if you can pinpoint the wrong contents, look into your source to find the bug.

Comment: There can be _up to __three__ padding bytes._ I see you only write one.

Comment: Have your code simply copy the file without inverting the colours, then look at the generated file using hexdump. Once you understand the difference I'm sure the error in your code will be obvious...

Comment: The scanline size is calculated as `(((bits) + 31) / 32 * 4)` with `bits` the number if bits in the pixels of the scanline. Subtract `width*pixelsize` to get the padding bytes.

Comment: Not only that, but you have done an `fseek` and **written** one padding byte to the input file instead of reading. Similarly you only output `0` or `1` padding bytes but there can be up to `3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bih.height; i++){
            for (uint32_t j = 0; j < bih.width; j++){
                uint32_t index = i * bih.width + j;
                fread(&p[index], 1, sizeof(Pixel), fin);
            }

            //if (padding_bytes > 0) {
            //fseek(fin, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            //for(int kk=0;kk<padding_bytes;kk++)
            //fputc('\0', fin);
            //}
              fseek(fin, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);      //ok
        }

//.....

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bih.height; i++){
            for (uint32_t j = 0; j < bih.width; j++){
                uint32_t index = i * bih.width + j;
                fwrite(&p[index], 1, sizeof(Pixel), fout);
            }

            //if (padding_bytes > 0){
            //  fseek(fout, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            //  fputc('\0', fout);
            //}
            //fseek(fout, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);
              for (int t = 0; t < padding_bytes; t++) fputc('\0', fout);   //ok
        }
```